# Order placing system and Multi-table entry

Tags: php, mysql, ajax, codeigniter, erp

I am doing this project, which is basically few modules from an ERP using PHP/MySQL (codeigniter framework).

I'm not sure how should I integrate the Order Placing mechanism (and other multi table dependent) features.
Eg. Customer's Order is managed by two MySQL tables, (Order and Order-Detail).
Order tables stores general order information, while Order-Detail stores ordered product information (quantity etc.), since an order can have more than one product ordered.

So, my questions are:

- How is this thing basically implemented (the logic behind it)?
- How it is called in the industry jargon (so I can google for ready JavaScript/AJAX or PHP libraries or snipets)?

Answer (score 1):

The term for this is relational databases

You can achieve building a relational database using either mysql itself using 'innoDB' driven tables.

The logic behind it is the following (in your case)

You have 3 tables:
- Users (with userid, username, userpassword, etc.)
- PlacedOrders (with orderid, userid, productid)
- OrdersDetails (with orderid, productid, orderdate, ammount, etc.)
- Products (with productid, productname, productweith, etc.)

Here all the '...id' names are primary keys

For users the primary id is userid
For placedorders the primary id is orderid
etc.

But some tables also have another '..id' that is the primary id from another table.
like userid in the table placedorders is the primary id from users
These id's are called foreignID's

These foreignID's are linked to eachother.

The logic behind it is that for the table placedorders you won't have to include the user name or password, stuff like that.

This prevents redundancy and can improve database efficiency when you have a lot of data.

Just one more hint about how this would be used in a website:
A user first logs in using data from the table users.
Then he goes to the product page and selects the product and the ammount he wants to order.

Now when placing the order an order will be made inside orderdetails
And a all the variables (orderid, productid and userid) will be combined in placedorders

Now for the user this isn't an improvement.

But for you (or the shop) it is.
This way to see who has ordered what using data from just the placedorders table

This way you can make a (search) page where you are just one click away from seeing the users' data, product detail and order detail.

Now with some handy scripting you can easily grab the appropriate data from the product, user and order and put these on one page while you don't have everything inside one big messy database

Comment: Thank you very much for the thorough explanation, but I know all of this.My question might need extra clarification.Basically, I want to have a from (which will be submitted to 2 tables- Order and OrderDetails),and will have the ability to add multiple products (hence, only the OrderDetails will have multiple entries). The point is to achieve this without reloading the page. Example, having a plus icon, that will add new form elements for new product entry. And when the final Submit will be clicked, 1 entry will go to Order(db table) and 1 or 1+ will go to OrderDetails,using the OrderID as FK.